# Access checksum of zfs dataset via cli

Tags: checksum, zfs

Is it possible to read/access the checksum of a zfs dataset? I want to access it to validate that it didnt change between boots.
Reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS#ZFS_data_integrity: Is the top checksum of a Merkle Tree like checksuming scheme in zfs accessible from userspace?

Comment: I hope you don't think ZFS recalculates the checksums of all the files in a ZFS filesystem every time a system is rebooted. Even if it did, what would you compare the checksums to?  And if you then found a difference, how would you know that the checksum you saved is the correct value?

Comment: No, I hope that there is some checksum of the compete dataset that is constantly updated. Something that would supply the functionality of a"dd if=/dev/sda of=/tmp/a ; md5sum /tmp/a", but instead of doing the checksum over the whole hd there is maybe a  checksum that is continuously updated. I ask this because I remember  some slides that show a hirarchicaly updated checksum.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS#ZFS_data_integrity I guess the question then is weather the Merkle Tree top checksum can be accessed from userspace.

Comment: Does `zdb -uuu poolname` give you enough information? You could read the specific blocks afterwards I think. Maybe the ZFS source code is also helpful if you know what to look for.

Comment: Not shure what the chsum of "zdb -uuu" actually reflects. The chsum entry seems to change between reboots even if all datasets that it contains are marked readonly and I dont access any files except of mounting the datasets. My naive thinking would assume that the chsum is persistent and marking the datasets readonly would protect it, but maybe metadata is written anyway.  Anyway, rdb is an interesting tool...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a (mainly for developers) tool called `zdb` which can do this. It's hard to use and its format is not always backwards compatible :-)

However, if all you want is to make sure that a filesystem hasn't changed, you can use snapshots for this purpose. First, create a snapshot at the point you want to compare to later on with `zfs snapshot <pool>/<fs>@<before-reboot-snap>`. Then there are two different ways to compare the filesystem to that snapshot later:

1. After reboot, run `zfs diff <pool>/<fs>@<before-reboot-snap> <pool>/<fs>`. This will show you a list of "diffs" between the snapshot and the current filesystem:

   ```
   # ls /tank/hello
   file1  file2  file3  file4  file5
   # zfs snapshot tank/hello@snap
   # zfs diff tank/hello@snap tank/hello
   # touch /tank/hello/file6
   # zfs diff tank/hello@snap tank/hello
   M       /tank/hello/
   +       /tank/hello/file6
   # rm /tank/hello/file6
   # zfs diff tank/hello@snap tank/hello
   M       /tank/hello/
   ```

   Note that even after I deleted the new file, the directory it lived in is still marked as modified.
2. Take another snapshot after the reboot, and then use `zfs send -i @<before-reboot-snap> <pool>/<fs>@<after-reboot-snap>` to create a stream of all the changes that happened between those snapshots, and analyze it with another tool called `zstreamdump`:

   ```
   zfs send -i @snap tank/hello@snap2 | zstreamdump
   BEGIN record
           hdrtype = 1
           features = 4
           magic = 2f5bacbac
           creation_time = 59036f98
           type = 2
           flags = 0x4
           toguid = 2f080aca53bff68e
           fromguid = 66a1da82cd5f1571
           toname = tank/hello@snap2
   END checksum = 91043406e5/38f3c4043049b/ed0867661876670/1e265bea2b6c3315
   SUMMARY:
           Total DRR_BEGIN records = 1
           Total DRR_END records = 1
           Total DRR_OBJECT records = 12
           Total DRR_FREEOBJECTS records = 5
           Total DRR_WRITE records = 1
           Total DRR_WRITE_BYREF records = 0
           Total DRR_WRITE_EMBEDDED records = 0
           Total DRR_FREE records = 17
           Total DRR_SPILL records = 0
           Total records = 37
           Total write size = 512 (0x200)
           Total stream length = 13232 (0x33b0)
   ```

   The example above shows that there have been a bunch of diffs -- anything like `WRITE`, `FREE`, `OBJECT`, or `FREEOBJECTS` indicates a change from the original snapshot.

Comment: Ok, maybe snapshots give enough confidence. I tried to get some useful information out of zdb but couldnt find a magical number that would change only if something was written. Dont know about the internals of zfs eather so I dont know actually what I should look for.

Comment: Yep, `zdb` is pretty much impenetrable unless you're a ZFS developer who has spent a lot of time with the on-disk format. That's why I'd suggest using one of the snapshotting methods instead.

Comment: Given all the "It's Pure Magic!!!!" hype Sun put out about ZFS in its early days, I was actually surprised when `zdb` was released, so I'm not surprised it's still impenetrable.  (Remember claims like "ZFS is ***always*** consistent on disk so no `fsck` or debugging tools will ***ever*** be needed!!!"?  Umm, yeah, sure. Just about all of us in the Sun/Solaris community had a good laugh at that...)